# How to Reset MySQL Workbench Root Password - Mac

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

**I need help, I forgot the root password, is there a way to reset/change it?
I uploaded some pictures.**

1.
[image: Opening MySQL and click on Start MySQL Server.]

2.
[image: Opening MySQL Workbench and click on root (This is the first message).]

3.
[image: After clicking on OK (This is the second message).]

4. I got the same message (Number 2).
5. 

[image: After clicking on OK - they asked to enter password.]

Answer (score 1):

Open the keychain app and go to the passwords section. You will see an entry in the list that corresponds to the Service entry, which is shown in your screenshot. Double click it to open its properties, select the checkbox "show password" (or whatever it is titled in your language), enter your Mac password and voilá - there is your MySQL password.

Comment: I deleted and downloaded MySQL and MySQL Workbench, Now when I click on 'root' I got a message and nothing happened. 
https://imgur.com/a/BL3bbO2

Comment: Seems you have a bit more trouble than just a missing password. Look in the log file of MySQL Workbench for any error message (see Help -> Show Logfile).